# Jquery Animate + Fade Effect bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fade

before posting I want to tell you "Sorry for my English".
I've got a problem with JQuery. http://socialworld.den-style.net/ if you click "Nascondi" under the Logo you will see that the #post go to the right and then "comes back" to its old position.
How do I can fix this error? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that `#post` gets a style of `overflow: hidden` during animation. I'm not immediately sure why that's moving everything right, but I would guess that the extra overflow setting is conflicting with the float on the left, moving the "center" of the page. (Having `overflow` set forces the box to expand around its contents).

(Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html for more info).

I would say that having a rule of `* { margin: 0 auto; }` is a little odd - I would recommend making the centering more specific.